# target text near element with css

Tags: css

I have some html that I can't change the output for and need to hide the input element and text that is near the element.
Example:

```html
<div id="outerdiv">
  some text
  <input name="inputname1"></input>
  hide this text
  <input name="hide_this_element"></input>
</div>
```

I'd like to hide the input named "hide_this_element" and the nearby text "hide this text".  How do I target the text near this element?

Comment: share the full code so we can see how is the CSS

Comment: What tag do these lines of code reside within?

Comment: There is a tag, lets just call it #outerdiv in this example.